# CSS: how to select all <element> within a .class?

Tags: css, css-selectors

How to select all instances of <element> whithin - and ONLY WITHIN - a .class ? (e.g. select all <h1> elements within the class ".mid-container", while excluding <h1> outside of ".mid-container").

For reference, this is a sample test of what I've tried, but it all failed as <h'x'> elements are being selectd OUTSIDE "mid-container" (and the code for `.mid-container.h2` doesn't even work) :

```
.mid-container>h1 {
  color: #EAF6F6;
}

.mid-container.h2 {
  color: #66BFBF;
}

.mid-container h3{
  color: #11999E;
}
```

Comment: You should add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first and third attempts are both correct, depending on the exact behavior you're after.

The first, `.mid-container > h1`, will select all `<h1>` elements that are immediate children of `.mid-container`.

The third, `.mid-container h1`, will select all `<h1>` elements anywhere beneath a `.mid-container` element.

If it's not working it's possible you're missing a closing tag or have other structural problems in your markup somewhere.

```css
.mid-container {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.mid-container h1 {
  color: blue;
}

.mid-container > h1 {
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Not in mid-container</h1>
</div>
<div class="mid-container">
  <h1>Immediate child of mid-container</h1>
  <div>
    <h1>Deeper child of mid-container</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <h1>Not in mid-container</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your third approach is the correct one. The first one will also work, but only if `.mid-container` is their immediate parent. The second code would apply if an element had both classes `.midcontainer` and `.h2` (which is obviously not the case).

```css
.mid-container h2{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="mid-container"><h2>Test</h2></div>

<h2>Test</h2>
```

I suggest you to read a bit about CSS selectors to understand them better: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp ;)

Comment: thanks. Your answer was great, but I had to mark the other answer as the "accepted one" as it was a little more complete (it even identified my error). But thank you for your explanation. Voted up!